# Codeception functional tests fail when run together, succeed when run seperatly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, codeception

I currently have two functional tests:

User login test

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('wedding guest');
$I->wantTo('Sign in to the website and see the home page');
$I->logIn('user@mysite.nl', 'secret');

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('');

$I->see('user page string');
```

Admin login test

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);

$I->am('The website admin');

$I->wantTo('Sign in to the website and see the admin page');

$I->login('admin@mysite.nl', 'mypass');

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/admin');
```

The code for the login method is the following:

```
public function login($email, $password){
    $I = $this->getModule('Laravel4');
    $I->amOnPage('login');
    $I->fillField("email", $email);
    $I->fillField("password",  $password);
    $I->click("Log in!");
}
```

When I run each test separate they succeed, but when I run the entire functional suite (only these two tests are a part of the suite) I get the following error:

```
vendor/bin/codecept run functional
...
Functional Tests (2) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to Sign in to the website and see the admin page (SignInWebsiteAdminCept)                                           Ok
...

1) Failed to sign in to the website and see the home page in 
SignInUserCept (/var/www/tests/functional/SignInUserCept.php)
Couldn't login "user@mysite.nl","secret":
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
...
#1  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1049
#2  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1017
#3  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:996
#4  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:776
#5  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:746
#6  /var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
#7  /var/www/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:332
#8  /var/www/tests/_support/FunctionalHelper.php:15
#9  /var/www/tests/functional/FunctionalTester.php:369
#10 /var/www/tests/functional/SignInWeddingGuestCept.php:7
```

It seems it can't find the route, while it clearly exists as I'm able to run the test successfully by executing `$ vendor/bin/codecept run functional SignInUserCept.php`

Is this a error on my end or a bug in codeception? I've tried to enable filters, with no luck. I also seem to be unable to set the environment to `local` instead of `testing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same exact problem! Finally figured it out. It appears to be a bug in Codeception v2.0.3

In your composer.json, set the version to 2.0.2 for now (until it gets fixed in a future release)

```
"codeception/codeception": "2.0.2"
```

Then run composer update to reflect the change:

```
php composer.phar update
```

And all the tests should now be working when running together. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it :) only problem now is that I stay logged in through different tests, is it bad practice to logout inside the test in order to make it pass?

Comment: @MegaWebs, glad it worked! Yeah, it's bad practice to logout in each test since each test should be independent of one another. What's interesting is, that the test not logging out was a bug in codeception that got fixed (see here: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1205)

Basically, it's codeception, not you. Hopefully the next version everything will be working nicely again. Good luck!